# Is it possible to increment the name of a symbol key in a ruby loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to print `n` and tag it on the end of the symbol key, each time `n` increments; is that possible?

This is the section of code...

```
# User info
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
@user = Hash.new
@user[:info] = client.user

# User media
@user[:recent_media] = Hash.new
@user[:recent_media][:p1] = client.user_recent_media
# user_recent_media only ever retrieves in 20 out of x image links; x being total profile images

(1..9).each do |n|
  page_max_id = @user[:recent_media][:p<n>].pagination.next_max_id
  return if page_max_id.nil?
  @user[:recent_media][:p<n+1>] = client.user_recent_media(max_id: page_max_id)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to avoid using symbols as your keys here because you're dynamically generating them. Symbols are never garbage collected, so it causes a memory leak. If you can change to strings, you can do string interpolation, e.g. `"p#{n + 1}"`. Otherwise, doing the same thing with `.to_sym` on the end will work, but be warned.

Comment: Eh, in this case it's controlled; creating arbitrary symbols is bad, but in this case, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: It's controlled in this one case he's given, but it's very possible this could switch to a `(1..n).each` loop instead.

Comment: @eric-andres I did not know that. If it is a `(1..n).each` loop, I should avoid using symbols? Should I avoid using symbols in this case, because a possible 10 symbols will be created?

Comment: I'm not going to say that you shouldn't use symbols here, but don't get into habit of dynamically creating symbols just because rails does so on everything. Strings work just as fine as hash keys.

Comment: @Crimbo You can use Hash#with_indifferent_access to get a hash that's indexable with strings or symbols. It's slower than a pure Symbol-indexed hash, but it's more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can symbolize strings. Try using `:"p#{n}"` or `"p#{n}".to_sym`.

Answer (score 2):

`:p1`, `:p2`, ... - these are not variables, they are symbols. You can construct a string and then cast it to a symbol, like this:

```
@user[:recent_media]["p#{n + 1}".to_sym] = ...
```

You should know that this technique can lead to memory leak, because symbols, once created, can't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..9).each do |n|
  page_max_id = @user[:recent_media]["p#{n}".to_sym].pagination.next_max_id
  return if page_max_id.nil?
  @user[:recent_media]["p#{n+1}".to_sym] = client.user_recent_media(max_id: page_max_id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@user[:recent_media][:"p#{n+1}"] = #...
```

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols):

> You may also create symbols by interpolation:
>
> ```
> :"my_symbol1"
> :"my_symbol#{1 + 1}"
> ```

Comment: How about the `@user[:recent_media][:p<n+1>]` bit in your 'another option'?

Comment: `p` takes the values from `:p1` to `:p10`, the loop is like `[:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8:, :p9].each`

Comment: That's understood, but looking at my code in the question, the second `n` needs to be one up from the last one two lines before: `[:p<n+1>]`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Removed that part from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`to_sym` is your friend!

```
@user[:recent_media]["p#{n+1}".to_sym] = client.user_recent_media(max_id: page_max_id)
```